# wxPython sample projects

Tags: wxpython

Can anyone tell where I would find free sample projects for wxPython?

Comment: @closevoters: how is this not a real question?  The OP is looking for help with learning how to program wxPython, and wants sample code to look at.

Answer (score 9):

Download the "Docs, Demos and Samples" from here:

http://www.wxpython.org/download.php

Run the demo app.  It's full of dozens of individual demos, each with their own source code visible.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a good wxPython tutorial at [zetcode.com:](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/)

It covers Menus and Toolbars, Layout Management, Events, Dialogs, Widgets, Drag and Drop, in18, Databases, Custom widgets, Using xml resource files, GDI,

Answer (score 2):

The two best places to look are:

SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=wxpython

The Python Package Index: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=wxpython&submit=search.